# Use a custom view for the front page without alias

Tags: views, theming

I am a Drupal Newbie, I have not learn't all the features yet.

I want to do the following.

I have created custom `twig` template for the front page.

By default I have default `Frontpage` view. I deleted it.

I've created a new view. And I want to use it as my default view for the front page, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I know about setting front page url in global settings. But it requires alias. Or it uses default frontpage.

So basically my questions are

1. How to create a view without alias, not exactly without, but with `/` or nothing for the front page.
2. How to associate a pathless view with a front page ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a view without alias, not exactly without, but with / or
>   nothing for the front page.
>
> How to associate a pathless view with a front page ?

1. You cannot create a pathless view **page**. (The default front-page view has a `/node` path)
2. Create a **block** View

Then go to blocks, and place your view block in a region. Content region perhaps?

Under Visibility settings check-mark "display only in" and put `<front>` so it only gets displayed in the front page.

Answer (score 0):

As No Sssweat explained, you cannot create a pathless view page. I would recommend installing [Empty Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/empty_page) module to get a blank front page and then assign a view to a content region.

You can have your url as / with empty page if you like. Give it a go and let me know if any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already tried / and it doesn't let me set this url for view

Comment: You will need to setup a empty page first with URL set to /. You then create a view block and assign this newly created view in a content region. Let me know if you need any help.